# linux command: conda Activate | cat myFileName.txt

Tags: shell, conda, virtual-environment

I am learning Linux commands and try to use it more in my day to day software development.

I created a `conda` environment and stored the environment path in a `txt` file. i.e. `myfile.txt`. For the next time, I don't need to remember the path to activate the environment. It would be `conda activate environment_path`

I also want not to open the `txt` file to copy past and get the activation done in one line. So I tried `conda activate | cat myFileName.txt`

But it didn't work. I'm not sure what was wrong. Some helps are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what the command you posted is supposed to do, but: `cat` processes stdin only if either no arguments are supplied, or if one of the arguments is a single dash (`-`). Therefore in your case, `cat` is ignoring it's stding, and the pipe does not make any sense.

Comment: @user1934428 not sure if you were the close voter, but the question seems sufficiently clear: the `myfile.txt` contains the name of the environment, so OP wants to get that value as argument to `conda activate`. The pipe is the point of confusion.

Comment: @merv : I voted to close because the OP just wrote _it didn't work_, without elaborating what effect he got instead of the expected one. Of course the pipeline is nonsense, and I pointed this out to the OP in my comment, hoping that this would point into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are running a standard `bash`-shell.

What you are currently doing, is [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) the output of `conda activate` to `cat myFileName.txt`.

Try instead this command

```
conda activate $(cat myFileName.txt)
```

This will first execute the command `cat myFileName.txt` and therefore read the content of `myFileName.txt`, using a subshell.
After that,  the command `conda activate` is run with the output of `cat myFileName.txt` in place.

For more information see [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution)